# basic c# architecture and class handling question

Tags: c#, architecture, class

Ok guys, this is very basic stuff I think.

I'm only getting familiar with C# and object oriented languages.

So here is a basic project I'm developping :

```
namespace MyProject  
{  
    class MyProject  
    {
        public Logger Logs = new Logger();
        public WebServer Web = new WebServer();

        static void Main()
        {  
            // blabla
        }  
    }  
}
```

The logger is there to simply create a log file and when its "Add(string str)" method is called, it adds a line in the log file.
The webserver is my own webserver, opening a socket etc ...
I'd like my webserver to be able to use my Add method of the logger... how am I supposed to achieve that ?

Inside my webserver class, using something like "MyProject.Logs.Add(string str)" doesn't seem to work.
So how can I reference it ?
I don't want to create a new instance of my Logger class inside my webserver, because I want to write everyting in the same text file (I might have more module running than just a webserver as well).
So I'd like to use the instance I created in my Main method, inside my Webserver class...

I hope this makes sense ...

Comment: You might want to check out log4net as apposed to rolling your own logging code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. `Logs` and `Web` should be private. Those are implementation details of your class. They're nobody else's business.
2. Pass the instance of your logger to your web server:

   ```
   public WebServer Web = new WebServer(Logs);
   ```

Your web server can now have its very own copy:

```
private Logger Logs {get;set;}

public WebServer(Logger logs)
{
    Logs = logs;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    Logs.Add("I did something!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, and yes, I realise Logs and Web should be private, I put them public hoping to be able to access them that way, but I was wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

`MyProject.Logs.Add(string str)` does not work because `Logs` member is not static, which means it can be different for different instances of your class (which are created by operator `new`). The compiler can't know which instance you are referring to if you don't specify it.

If you mark `Logs` as `static`, then it will work.

However, making it static makes your project less customizable (for example you will not be able to start two web-servers with two different log-files in the same program). That's why what **John Saunders** suggested is usually considered better.

Comment: Interesting.
Like you said, I think I'm gonna go with what John said, it does indeed offer more flexibility than making these static.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by passing a reference to the `Logger` instance you created in within `MyProject` to your instance of `WebServer`.

In your `WebServer` class, you can make a property (a getter/setter) of type `Logger`, so that WebServer knows about the Logger you want to use. Another alternative (probably better) is to add a parameter to the constructor of WebServer that takes the Logger. Pseudo code for adding the property:

```
public class WebServer
{
    public WebServer(Logger l)
    {
        Log = l;
    }

    //relevant code....
    public Logger Log { get; set; } //Short hand property declaration, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx
}
```

From inside the `WebServer` class, you can use the logger like `Logger.Add("some text...");`
Then, in your `Main` method, you can pass in your instance of `Logger` like so:

```
namespace MyProject  
{  
    class MyProject  
    {
        public static Logger Logs = new Logger();
        public static WebServer Web;

        static void Main()
        {  
            Web = new WebServer(Logs);
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This will not compile. You are accessing instance members from static method.

Comment: Good call, copied from the OP. That's what I get for typing in the editor and not VS.

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty much what John Saunders says, I appreciate the help tho :)